# How to let app to close its GUI and work in background in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I need to know if there is any way to let my application close its GUI once I clicked a specific button and complete its work in the background... 
If I opened the application again I need it to resume its work which was in the background and I need to resume the same status of the button as in the background.

I need to perform this task programaticaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to do the work in background. And to remove the UI and not actually close the app (kill the process) you need the following code to execute on the button.This code will bring up the Home screen and will let android  decide that if app has spent to much time in background and finally android may close it but the work you already defined in service remains running untill it finishes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Keep Rockin :D

Comment: yes this is exactly what i need but unfortunately when i open the app again  i does not get the previous status for the button (set enable to false) i.e. the app starts new task i does not resume the previous task from background ... could you provide me by additional information plz

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to do so on android is to create a `service`. Services are intended to work on the background without having a gui shown. You can easily communicate with the service and share data between your application and service at anytime. Even if you reloaded your app